# Timed out compile unless I delete bibliography

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, compiling, sharelatex

I have a document that won't compile unless I delete the bibliography. All of the subfiles compile individually (but they don't refer to the bibliography file).

It was working fine for weeks, and all of a sudden it won't compile when all I've done is add some text to one of the subfiles. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,nobalancelastpage,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{graphicx,bm,times}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} \usepackage{color} \usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfiles} \usepackage{amsmath, hyperref}
\usepackage{caption, pbox, multirow}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\subfile{0}
\subfile{1}
\subfile{2}
\subfile{3}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

I'm writing and compiling in ShareLatex, the error message says "Timed Out" but this is still the case when I remove all of the subfiles. Take out the bibliography and it compiles but of course I then get a load of [?] instead of actual references.

Any ideas?? I'm completely stumped.

EDIT: When I compile without \bibliography{refs} I get the error message "You can't use a prefix with `\begingroup'."
This prefix doesn't appear in my code, and the file it says it is in, isn't a file in my project.

Comment: What about dropping the `.bib` extension? You should be using `\bibliography{refs}`.  The three `\setcounter{secnumdepth}` commands aren't needed: just set it once -- presumably to '3'.

Comment: Do you know whether was a recent update/change on ShareLaTeX's side? I can't see anything on [their twitter feed](https://twitter.com/sharelatex)...

Comment: Welcome! by the way... And ***what*** did you add...? What if you exclude just that subfile? If excluding that doesn't help, the problem is not whatever you added... We will need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to really help. (We can guess a lot without one, but you may not like guessing games if you need an actual solution.)

Comment: Thanks for the swift responses.I removed the .bib extension and it still won't compile. I'm pretty sure the issue isn't due to a change with ShareLatex as I have other projects that compile. And as for what I added, it was just text. The file still compiles with the text I added if I remove \bibliography{refs}.

Comment: I downloaded the project and tried to compile it using TeXworks, and that seems to have an issue every time there is a hyphen in one of my references, but there were hyphens there when it was compiling previously.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @user76486 please see my comment about merging accounts.

Comment: Then we need an MWE. Or an MnWE (Minimal non-Working Example).

Comment: Well, then you're getting close to finding the problem. What's up with these problematic bib entries, right?  Perhaps you could post one or more of them so people who spend their Friday nights on this site have something to do....

Comment: @JohnKormylo: be more careful with your advices. The bib is the database and not a file that you can delete like the aux-file.

Comment: Sometimes I have to delete the aux file in order to get a file to compile.  In your case you might want to delete both the aux and bbl file.

Comment: As it stands, without logs and similar, we can't hope to answer this (sorry).